# Add a vertical line to a plot in R

Tags: r, plot, time-series

Maybe you can help me. I need to plot a time series, let's call it, ts for that, I use the following code:

```
plot(ts,col="royalblue", ylab="time series plot", main = "Plot", grid.col=NA)
```

But I also need to plot in the same plot, a vertical line at the date 18-03-2020 (March 18, 2020). I tried with the following line of code but I don't get any vertical line:

```
geom_vline(xintercept = 03-18-2020, color="red", linetype="doted", size=2.5)
```

And also with this one:

```
abline(a=NULL,b=NULL,h=NULL,v="18-03-2020", col="red")
```

And this one:

```
date1 <- as.Date("2020-03-18") + 0:99
abline(v=as.Date(date1))
```

But with none of them I get the vertical line I need.

What am I doing wrong? could you help me?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 11):

You can do it with `abline`. Set `v` and position of x axis where you want the horizontal line. In this example `v=0.4`

```
plot(ts,col="royalblue", ylab="time series plot", main = "Plot", grid.col=NA)
abline(v=0.4, col="blue")
```

[image]